# Postgresql создание триггера - ошибка триггера

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер

Создал триггер:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pim_individual_doc_active_true
  AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT
  ON pim_individual_doc
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE pim_individual_doc_active_true_func();
```

И триггерную функцию:

```
create or replace function pim_individual_doc_active_true_func() returns trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF ((NEW.type_id = 19 OR old.type_id = 19) AND (old.expire_dt is NULL or new.expire_dt is null))  THEN
        update pim_individual_doc set is_active = TRUE WHERE id = OLD.id or id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
    RETURN null;
END
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Но при обновлении строки, выходит ошибка:

```
[54001] ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded Подсказка: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate. Где: SQL statement "SELECT set_config('aud.when'::TEXT, to_char(cur_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:MS'), true)" PL/pgSQL function audit_trigger_fun() line 23 at PERFORM SQL statement "update pim_individual_doc set is_active = TRUE WHERE id = OLD.id" PL/pgSQL function pim_individual_doc_active_true_func() line 4 at SQL statement SQL statement "update pim_individual_doc set is_active = TRUE WHERE id = OLD.id" PL/pgSQL function pim_individual_doc_active_true_func() line 4 at SQL statement SQL statement "update pim_individual_doc set is_active = TRUE WHERE id = OLD.id" PL/pgSQL function pim_individual_doc_active_true_func() line 4 at SQL statement SQL statement "update pim_individual_doc set is_active = TRUE WHERE id = OLD.id" PL/pgSQL function pim_individual_doc_active_true_func() line 4 at SQL statement SQL statement " ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы из триггера выполняете обновление этой самой таблицы. И из рекурсии, судя по всему, не выходите. Возможно, вы хотели в `if` в триггере так же проверять на `AND NOT NEW.is_active`? Или что-нибудь в этом духе для определения, когда уже хватит выполнять `update`.